# Batch file fault or cl.exe lying for compilation result/exit

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a batch file that tests a header policy (each header must include/resolve its own dependencies), but it appears cl.exe is returning success even though it is actually failing..

Script without comments is:

```
@echo off

set FNAME=temp
set OBJFILE=%FNAME%.obj
set SRCFILE=%FNAME%.cc

for /f "delims=|" %%i in ('dir /b /s ..\include\*.h') do (
    ( echo #include "%%i" & echo void test^(^){} ) > %SRCFILE%
    echo %%i
    "%VCINSTALLDIR%\bin\cl.exe" /c /W4 %SRCFILE% > NUL 2>&1

    if not ERRORLEVEL 0 goto failed
)
goto success

:failed
echo.
echo Compile failed.
goto fin

:success
echo.
echo Success.
goto fin

:fin
if exist %OBJFILE% del %OBJFILE% > NUL
if exist %SRCFILE% del %SRCFILE% > NUL
```

I suspect the fault lies with the errorlevel detection (I've read [raymond chens article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx%20raymond%20chens%20article), as well as other SO posts about its caveats), but all attempted variations have also failed in the same way, making me think [cl.exe is lying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebh0y918(v=vs.120).aspx). I could be completely wrong, so I was going to check with ProcMon - but sadly it's crashing at the moment.

Is it just me being stupid?

I'm currently forcing failure in a header file using `FakeType blah;`, which cl.exe does output if I redirect to file:

```
...\include\fail.h(1) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'blah'
...\include\fail.h(1) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: Try `if !ERRORLEVEL! neq 0 goto failed` with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, because `if not ERRORLEVEL 0 ...` means: "If errorlevel is less than 0". Carefully read the description at `if /?`

Comment: Try `if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto failed` as probably no [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) required.

Comment: @Aacini That's the one! Nuances with the `if`... are you able to put it as an answer and I'll accept, thanks.

Comment: @JosefZ that does appear to work, though I don't trust cl.exe to never return a negative value (it's not stated), hence I was always using 0!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The programs usually return an error code via an ERRORLEVEL value greater than zero; however, cl.exe may return positive or negative values of ERRORLEVEL when there is an error, and a value of zero if it is OK. The usual form:

```
if errorlevel num ...
```

is true if the errorlevel is *greater or equal* than the given number, so

```
if not ERRORLEVEL 0 goto failed
```

will be true when the errorlevel is *less than zero*. There are two ways to test if errorlevel is exactly zero:

```
if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 goto success
```

that is, if errorlevel is greater or equal zero and less than 1. Perhaps the clearest way is to directly compare the errorlevel value:

```
if !errorlevel! equ 0 goto success
```

Remember that this form requires `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning.

Comment: kudos for the extra detail, hope it helps others in future. I opt for the latter form since it looks more syntactically valid ;)

Comment: But `if !errorlevel! equ 0 goto success` jumps out from the `for` loop maybe abortively. Hence you need to use either `if !errorlevel! neq 0 goto failed`, or  two consecutive `IF`s in _logical OR_ sense: `if not ERRORLEVEL 0 goto failed` and back to back `if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto failed`

Comment: Correct - I was referring to using the method as opposed to the actual content :)